Each section of the Shemonei Esrei representing a section in the Beis HaMikdosh
I heard in the name of Rav Glatstein that the morning-tefillos represent certain areas in the Beis HaMikdosh. For example:

All the tefilos that precede Birchas Hashachar, represents the Ezras Nashim (The Women's Courtyard), for example "yigdal".

Birchas Hashachar consists of 15 brachos. Why 15? Because to get from the Ezras Nashim to the area of the Ezras Yisroel, there are exactly 15 steps. So each bracha of the Birchas Hashachar, represents one step.

Parshas HaTamid (the Korbonos-section of shacharis (morning prayer) is read during shacharis. Korbonos represent the mizbeach.

So, now we are at the mizbeach, when reciting the Parshas HaTamid. But we need to go to the Heichal - the area of the Holy of Holies. You'll need to climb 12 steps. The platform of the ulam  has 13 steps - corresponding to the "Thirteen Principles of Torah Exegesis"


@Avishai Tebeka got the English translation of what I was looking for, but does anyone know if this can also be found in the original Hebrew-version?

In sefer Iyun Tefilla by Rav Shimon Schwab it can be found in the intro from page xxx-xxxiii

@AvishaiTebeka Thanks, but I can't find it in the Artscroll-version of the sefer. Is it on page 30-33?

I'll just send the pictures as an answer to make it easier

Can be found in sefer Iyun Tefilla by Rav Shimon Schwab from page xxx-xxxiii, sorry if formatting or pictures don't work it's my first time posting pictures :)





Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for. Any idea if this can also be found in his original?

Not sure, sorry

In addition to what Avishai Tebeka wrote, the original can be found in the sefer Iyun Tefillah by Rav Shimon Schwab (פתיחה, p. 22):

ולאור הקדמה זו, כשנתבונן בסדר תפלת שחרית שתקנו חכמים, נראה שמבנה התפלה דומה לסדר הבנין של הבית המקדש, וכאילו המתפלל עולה בקודש דרך שערי העזרה וההיכל עד התקרבו לפני ולפנים להתייחד עם קונו
And in light of this introduction, when we reflect on the order of the Shacharis prayer established by the sages, it appears that the structure of the prayer is similar to the order of the building of the Temple, as if the worshipper ascends in sanctity through the gates of the courtyard and the sanctuary until approaching the innermost sanctum to commune with his Maker.

